# FosuserBundle ( The path "fos_user.from_email.address" cannot contain an empty value, but got null. )

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, sonata-admin

I have a problem when I Install FOsuserbundle. This is my problem in result:

[image]

this is my config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

security:

```
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        #http_basic: ~

        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
        #form_login: ~
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

and this is my routing.yml:

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

Comment: Seems like the parameter mailer_user is not defined.  Have you added it to say parameters.yml?

Answer (score 34):

The problem is with your parameters.yml file:

```
parameters:
    ...
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
```

Change that to something then you won't get the error.

Comment: Was that the correct answer? If so can you click the checkmark by my answer. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me. They should include info about it in their official guide for configurating FOSUserBundle at http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

Answer (score 13):

The FOSUserBundle has built-in support for sending emails in two different instances.

These values cannot be null, so if you try to set the value of these properties either with "" or ~, the problem will persist.
Give values other than null. It will work.

```
# /app/config.yml
fos_user:
    from_email:
        address: "testapp@testapp.com"
        sender_name: "Test App"
```